# Refinerycms Rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, refinerycms

When trying to run a new refinerycms application with ruby 1.9.2 rails 3.2.1 and refinerycms 2.0.1 am getting this Error in production. I am curious to what is causing this as my app is right out off the box.

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-11 01:21:11 -0800
Processing by Refinery::PagesController#home as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>:en}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'refinery_roles'):
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:470:in `table_structure'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:351:in`columns'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:12:in `block in initialize'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in`yield'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `default'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in`columns'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:248:in `column_names'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:261:in`column_methods_hash'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:69:in `all_attributes_exists?'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:27:in`method_missing'
  refinerycms-authentication (2.0.1) app/models/refinery/role.rb:14:in `[]'
  refinerycms-core (2.0.1) lib/refinery/application_controller.rb:53:in`just_installed?'
  refinerycms-core (2.0.1) lib/refinery/application_controller.rb:73:in `refinery_user_required?'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in`*run*_157096296043845177__process_action_*370528316792604795*_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in`_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in`process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in`block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in`process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in`process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in`process'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in`dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in`call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in`call'
  journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in`each'
  journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:589:in`call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in`method_missing'
  journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in`each'
  journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:589:in`call'
  warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in`catch'
  warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in`call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in`call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in`call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in`context'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in`call'
  dragonfly (0.9.10) lib/dragonfly/cookie_monster.rb:9:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in`call'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in`block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__215402801072025143__call__3538488024182103853__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in`__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in`run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  dragonfly (0.9.10) lib/dragonfly/middleware.rb:13:in`call'
  dragonfly (0.9.10) lib/dragonfly/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in`forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in`lookup'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in`call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in`fetch'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in`call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in`call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in`call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in`call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in`call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in`call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in`forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in`lookup'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in`call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in`call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in`call'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in`catch'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in`process'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:38:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in`run_machine'
  eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61:in`start'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in`run'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in`start'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in`tap'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
  script/rails:6:in`require'
  script/rails:6:in `'

Comment: same problems here. Any solution?

Comment: OK I have been going at this all day, I believe my issue was that I forgot to mention that this thing works perfectly in development, It's only when i try it in production does it run into this problem, the issue with the refinery_roles has to do with my production database not being migrated. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run 'rake db:migrate' inside your rails application. That will createperfumery specific tables in db. I got the same error yesterday and this solved it.